# Creating nodes for a sorted list in Java

Tags: java, list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I have to create a node class that is sorted alphabetically, so I think that it is a single-linked list. I am supposed to create it "recursively" and I am confused with this. I have to implement basic methods to query the list, which are easy enough but I'm stuck on the initializing part and especially adding nodes.

Any help?

My code looks like this right now :

```
public class SortedSetNode implements Set {
   protected String value;
   protected SortedSetNode next;

   public SortedSetNode(String v, SortedSetNode n) {
      //value = v;
      //next = n;
   }
   public SortedSetNode(String v) {
      //value = v;
   }
```

}

Comment: If you uncomment the lines, and remove the `implements Set` you should be fine. A Set != Node

Comment: @PeterLawrey even though you gave him a couple of good advices, I got the feeling that he wants someone to implement it for him (HW)

Comment: I don't want anyone to implement it for me. I just want to understand better how to build a set of nodes recursively...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would implements a sorted list.  Note: a list is not a set.

```
public class SortedList<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    private SortedNode<E> head = null;

    public void add(E e) {
        SortedNode<E> node = new SortedNode<E>(e);
        if (head == null || head.e.compareTo(e) <= 0) {
            node.next = head;
            head = node;
        } else {
            head.add(node);
        }
    }
}

public class SortedNode<E extends Comparable<E>>  {
    final E e;
    SortedNode<E> next;

    public SortedNode(E e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    public void add(SortedNode<E> node) {
        if (next == null || e.compareTo(node.e) <= 0) {
            node.next = next;
            next = node;
            return;
        }
        next.add(node);
    }
}
```